# Apache Camel conditional routing didn't work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am trying to transfer file by using Apache Camel conditional routing. The condition is if filename starts with "041PACS". It created a .camel directory on source folder. But don't know why file didn't transfer to destination folder. There is no error in console.

I am using Camel 2.17.3 and JDK 1.7.

## applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-autowire="byName"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.17.3.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<import resource="actionRoutes.xml" />

    <camelContext streamCache="true"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <package>in.client.camelbean</package>
        <routeContextRef ref="actionRoutes" />
    </camelContext> 

</beans>
```

## actionRoutes.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.17.3.xsd ">

    <!-- Only the routeContext is here -->

    <routeContext id="actionRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

   <route id="route36">
            <from uri="file:\\home\41\CAMEL\reports" />         
           <choice>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${header.CamelFileName.startsWith("041PACS")} == 'true'</simple>
                            <to uri="file:\\home\41\CAMEL\result?noop=true" />                  
                    </when>
           </choice>
        </route>

</routeContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: @halfer..Why do you need edit my post???

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the Unix way of File Seperator ?

file://home/41/CAMEL/result?noop=true

Comment: I think simple language will not work. I am using filter, its working fine. Thanks for your help.